# How to add a specific div element to the first post in a row?

Tags: loop

I was asking how to add a custom div element to the latest recent post that was uploaded. How can I do this?

My code:

```
<ul class="entrybox">
                <?php 
                    $args = array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'paged' => $paged);
                    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                    $count = 0;
                ?>

                <?php if ($loop) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <li class="grid_4 portfolio-post">

                <?php if ($count == 1) echo '<div class="newest">NEW</div>'; ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <header class="post-thumb">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-portfolio'); ?>
                    </header><!-- End header.post-thumb -->

                    <aside>
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    </aside><!-- End aside -->
                </a>
                </li><!-- End li.grid_4 portfolio-post -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <p>No portfolio items were found! I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul><!-- End ul.entrybox -->
```

I have tried it with:

`<?php if ($count == 1) echo '<div class="newest">NEW</div>'; ?>`

But this is not working.

Hope someone has a solution!

Comment: Can you show us your code? What have you done so far?

Comment: Check my code above please. @KrzysiekDróżdż

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... Of course it doesn't work - `$count` is undefined and you never change it's value.

You probably want to have there something like this:

```
<?php if ($loop) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="grid_4 portfolio-post">

        <?php if ($loop->current_post == 0) echo '<div class="newest">NEW</div>'; ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <header class="post-thumb">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-portfolio'); ?>
            </header><!-- End header.post-thumb -->

            <aside>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </aside><!-- End aside -->
        </a>
        </li><!-- End li.grid_4 portfolio-post -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p>No portfolio items were found! I'm not sure what you're looking for.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul><!-- End ul.entrybox -->
```

`WP_Query` already has it's own counter (`current_post`), so you don't have to define your own.

Comment: Maybe one little question for you. If I want to replace that div for an image. I past it inside the echo. But because I call the images map with a custom print like `print IMAGES;` how can I make it work?

Comment: Again, show your code - it's a little bit hard to guess, what are you trying to achieve exactly...